# SQL Database with offline filegroup

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I'm using SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise and yesterday I had an hardware-error. During this error one disk went offline, which contains a very unimportant part (filegroup) of the database. Accidentially this part was stored only on one single disk which failed.

To minimize the outtage we decided to set the missing filegroup OFFLINE and started over.
At the evening I tried to rebuild the database, but I failed.

My problem is the following

- The filegroup is offline
- The tables from these filegroup are orphaned
- I'm unable to delete these orphaned tables, because filegroup is offline
- I've restored a backup from two days ago with a fully functional database
- I've tried to restore the missing filegroup from backup DB to production DB, but the database-file stucks in state "RESTORING" (sys.database_files)
- so I'm unable to restore these filegroup
- I'd be very satisfied when I'm able to kill these filegroup and recreate the necessary tables from backup

Does anyone know a way to get out of this crisis?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1.  Did you restore "with recovery"?  2.  Did you try "Restore YourDatabase with recovery"?  3.  How long did you wait for restoring to finish?

Comment: I tried to restore "with recovery" and also executed restore db with recovery, without success. I waited more than 15 minutes, and the state didn't change.

Comment: I'm experiencing a very similar issue. I restored a partial db and now can't bring the filegroups online.